# can we make this say "Just Now 'AppName' via iOS" in facebook while posting the image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, ios6

I am working on facebook ios6.  when i am posting the image it displays like below image.
[image]

i want to include my "AppName"

My code is

```
    -(void)facebookbtnclicked
{
    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];
    ACAccount *account = [[ACAccount alloc] initWithAccountType:accountType];
    NSLog(@"%@, %@", account.username, account.description);
    {
        SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

        SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler myBlock = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
            if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {

                NSLog(@"Cancelled");
            } else
            {
                NSLog(@"Done");
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" message:@"Image Posted Successfully, Please Create an other Tattoo" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                UINavigationController *navController=self.navigationController;
                [navController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
                [alert show];
            }
            [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
        };
        controller.completionHandler =myBlock;
        [controller setInitialText:self.textMsg];
        [controller addImage:appDelegate.shareImage];//This image i am posting
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];
    }
}
```

Give me any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use native sharing dialog, you cannot change it.

**Old method of posting photo:**

```
NSDictionary *param = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YOURIMAGE.png"], @"picture", nil];
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
    parameters:param
    HTTPMethod:@"POST"
    completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                        id result,
                        NSError *error) 
{
    if (error) 
        NSLog(@"failed");
    else 
        NSLog(@"posted");
}];
```

Comment: what i have to do now . My client wants to change this AppName via ios @Paramasivan Samuttiram

Comment: can u suggest me another way with out using native sharing dialog @Paramasivan Samuttiram

Comment: Can you please try our old method of posting via FBRquest? http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/publish-to-feed-ios-sdk/

Comment: can we send image by using this code http://pastie.org/5552096 @Paramasivan Samuttiram

Comment: I updated source code with my answer. Main thing is you have to send "picture" parameter to me/feed.

Comment: ok..Thank u.. i am trying that code   @Paramasivan Samuttiram

Comment: i tried this one... i am getting this error  :   Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x9df7720 {com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 100;
            message = "(#100) picture URL is not properly formatted";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
    code = 400;
}, com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=400}  @Paramasivan Samuttiram

Comment: How you modified the [UIImage imageNamed:@"YOURIMAGE.png"] for your case?

Comment: i given like this  NSDictionary *param = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pencil_new.png"], @"picture", nil]; @ Paramasivan Samuttiram

Comment: if i send only the message (NSDictionary *param = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"hello this is Testing",@"message", nil];) it is working good. But when i send image it throws an error  @Paramasivan Samuttiram

Comment: pencil_new.png is inside your project? If it is a valid picture, please try to send NSData as parameter, like, NSData *dataPicture = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"pencil_new.png"], 1.0)

Comment: yes.. it is in my project .. But the paramater is @"picture".. is it take NSData?  @Paramasivan Samuttiram

Comment: i did like that still i am getting the same error . i wrote  NSDictionary *param = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:dataPicture, @"picture", nil];  @Paramasivan Samuttiram

Answer (score -1):

You must create an Facebook App id (on creating it you can add your appname)and include it in your .plist file                                              http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/#coding